# Sunspot's equivalent of "IS NOT NULL"

Tags: sunspot

I want to search for a field that has any values, essentially SQL's `IS NOT NULL`. I tried

```
with :fieldA
```

thinking it means 'with value'. However it does not work. What's the Sunspot way to specify `IS NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that I need

```
without :fieldA, nil
```

It's kind of obvious once I know it.